# "Percentage of time that.." vs "Percentage of time.."

Tags: relative-pronouns

Which one of the following is grammatically correct?

> Percentage of time **that** the system will be available to the users

OR

> Percentage of time, the system will be available to the users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is common to drop “that” as the introduction of a clause; there is nothing ungrammatical in doing so.

If you do so in writing, however, you should not insert a comma in place of “that.”